# Variables treated differently than Values

Tags: python, variables, equation

I tried to add a dictionary to a list, but I made the mistake of using the += operator. After discovering the bug, I noticed that if I run

```
a = []
a += {'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
print(a)
```

I get ['b', 'c', 'd'].
If I run the same thing, but I directly reference [], I get an error.
`SyntaxError: 'list' is an illegal expression for augmented assignment`

I expected the results to be the same, but apparently x is treated differently even if it's value is set to [].

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, `+=` is an *augmented assignment* operator.  The left-hand-side is expected to be a variable name.  You can't use it where the left-hand-side is a literal expression like `[]` any more than you can use a regular assignment operator on a literal:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] = [2, 3, 4]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [1, 2, 3] = [2, 3, 4]
     ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

What you might want is the `extend` function, which mutates a list in almost exactly the same way as the `+=` operator, and is perfectly valid on a literal like `[]`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend({'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4})
>>> a
['b', 'c', 'd']
>>> [].extend({'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4})
```

but note that this is pointless since having extended your anonymous empty list you can't access it the same way you can access `a`.

Comment: The `+=` operator with a list on the left hand side doesn't create a new list. It's functionally identical to `list.extend`. There might be some minor differences in corner cases, like what exceptions get raised when things don't work correctly, but if they work, they work identically.

Comment: In current CPython, `list.__iadd__` [directly calls `list.extend` internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L989).